# Google Sheets Script visiblesheets assistance

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently having some issues, I'm a novice (at best) when it comes to google sheets, even more so with the Script.

I currently have -

```
    // global var
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  showGoToSheet();
}
function showGoToSheet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Please Select Search Tool")
    .setHeight(400).setWidth(450);
  var sPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)
    .setSize(440, 400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize(400, 400);
  var fTable = app.createFlexTable().setCellPadding(5).setSize(400, 400)
    .setCellSpacing(0).setBorderWidth(1); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();   
  var goToSheetClick = app.createServerHandler('handleGoToSheetClick');     
  for (var i=0, iLen=allsheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    fTable.setWidget(i, 0, app.createButton(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name)
      .setWidth(200).addClickHandler(goToSheetClick)); 
  }
  app.add(sPanel.add(vPanel.add(fTable)));
  ss.show(app);
}

function handleGoToSheetClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.source).activate();
  app.close();   
  return app; 
}
```

As most of you figured out, this opens a "popup" on sheet open that asks me what sheet I want to go to. However, on my Google Sheet I have several search tools and even more databases. This "getsallsheets" and displays "hidden" and/or "protected" sheets in its list that the other users have no capability to access.

Is there anyway I can restrict access to all "visible" sheets? and it will then ignore the hidden/protected? Or even if it will just display a list of visible and ignore hidden. I can live with hiding my protected sheets :)

Unfortunately, due to the nature of my search functions I cannot try this out without some form of edit access. So my dilema is I dont really have much facility of trial and error outside of work.

Thanks

Any help is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but it may work.

```
        // global var
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  showGoToSheet();
}
function showGoToSheet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Please Select Search Tool")
    .setHeight(400).setWidth(450);
  var sPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)
    .setSize(440, 400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize(400, 400);
  var fTable = app.createFlexTable().setCellPadding(5).setSize(400, 400)
    .setCellSpacing(0).setBorderWidth(1); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();   
  var goToSheetClick = app.createServerHandler('handleGoToSheetClick');     
  for (var i=0, iLen=allsheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if(allsheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true){
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    fTable.setWidget(i, 0, app.createButton(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name)
      .setWidth(200).addClickHandler(goToSheetClick)); 
  }
  app.add(sPanel.add(vPanel.add(fTable)));
  ss.show(app);
  }
}

function handleGoToSheetClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.source).activate();
  app.close();   
  return app; 
}
```

I've just added this part to the loop

```
if(allsheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true)
```

I've never used the `isSheetHidden` function, but I think this is what's needed and possibly I've put it in the right place.

**EDIT BELOW THIS LINE**

I tested my code and I noticed it was still creating spaces for the buttons that were not there. So instead of creating the table right away. I've just pushed the names into an array and added another loop.

```
        // global var
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  showGoToSheet();
}
function showGoToSheet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Please Select Search Tool")
    .setHeight(400).setWidth(450);
  var sPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true)
    .setSize(440, 400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize(400, 400);
  var fTable = app.createFlexTable().setCellPadding(5).setSize(400, 400)
    .setCellSpacing(0).setBorderWidth(1); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();   
  var goToSheetClick = app.createServerHandler('handleGoToSheetClick');     
 var visSheet = [];
  for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) {

    if(allsheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true){
      visSheet.push(allsheets[i].getName())}
  }

    for (var x =0;x<visSheet.length;x++){
    var sheet_name = visSheet[x];
    fTable.setWidget(x, 0, app.createButton(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name)
      .setWidth(200).addClickHandler(goToSheetClick)); 
    }
  app.add(sPanel.add(vPanel.add(fTable)));
  ss.show(app);

}

function handleGoToSheetClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.source).activate();
  app.close();   
  return app; 
}
```

The only real changes to your original code is this section.

```
 var visSheet = [];
  for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) {

    if(allsheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true){
      visSheet.push(allsheets[i].getName())}
  }

    for (var x =0;x<visSheet.length;x++){
    var sheet_name = visSheet[x];
    fTable.setWidget(x, 0, app.createButton(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name)
```

Comment: Thank you Munkey :) I've started watching a recommended Youtube channel to learn Excel, Excelisfun (not really) :) Thank you for all your help. The Script worked just like I wanted. Now just need to reverse engineer it to learn it :)

Comment: @McSheehy Firstly just to be clear, this is Goggle Sheets and Javascript I helped you with. Not excel and VBA. While some formulas translate from excel to google. I'm not sure VBA translates direct to Javascript. If you want to learn basic Javascript, try codeacademy.com